# ReactJS axios call in useEffect shows - Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from my API and store it into a variable in react using setState hook in a variable.My codes are here

---

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
const rest_base = wpbpressdata.rest_url
const api = rest_base + '/services'

const ServicesCategory = () => {
    const [services, setServices] = useState(null)
    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get( api )
            .then( (res) =>{ 
                setServices(res.data) 
            })
    }, [] )
    return(
            services === null ? 'loading' : services.map = (data) => {
                <h3>{data.service_name}</h3>
            }
    )
}
export default ServicesCategory
```

But I am getting this error `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: can you edit your post and add what your `res.data` looks like?

Comment: {
 services === null ? 'loading' : services.map(service => <h3>{service.service_name}</h3>)
}

Comment: Because of your mistake of assigning the map function, you return the map function itself. So the error makes sense and you should return JSX instead of "loading".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
 services === null ? 'Loading' : services.map(p => <h3>{p.service_name}</h3>)
}
```

Call the `map` function not assign

Comment: Hi, its working but i could not understand why mine did not work and this worked. It will be helpful. I am accepting this answer,thanks

Comment: The `map` function is an array method. So you have to call this function not assign. And callback function what you give as function parameter (`p => <h3>{p.service_name}</h3>`) will return a React Component. React will render this.

Answer (score 0):

if your `services` is null return 'loading' which is a string wich is not JSX

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
const rest_base = wpbpressdata.rest_url
const api = rest_base + '/services'

const ServicesCategory = () => {
    const [services, setServices] = useState(null)
    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get( api )
            .then( (res) =>{ 
                setServices(res.data) 
            })
    }, [] )
    return(
          <>{
            !services ?<h1> 'loading'</h1> : services.map(data) => {
                <h3>{data.service_name}</h3>
            }}</>
    )
}
export default ServicesCategory
```

Comment: but in ReactJs you can return a string without any <hx> </hx> or text tag

Comment: If you using as component it need to be return jsx

Comment: he already have it in `<> </>` tag, so will work

Comment: <>{
            !services ?'loading': services.map = (data) => {
                <h3>{data.service_name}</h3>
            }}</>
this will also work

Comment: Not working this one

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
const rest_base = wpbpressdata.rest_url
const api = rest_base + '/services'

const ServicesCategory:React.FC<any> = () => {
    const [services, setServices] = useState(null)
    
    const fetchServices=async ()=>{
       const response=await axios.get( api )
       if(response){
          setServices(response.data) 
       }
    }
    useEffect( () => {
        fetchServices()
    }, [] )

    if(!services){
      return (<p>Loading...</p>);
    }

    return(
             services.map = (data, index) => 
                <h3 key={`service${index}`}>{data.service_name}</h3>  
    )
}
export default ServicesCategory
```

Comment: Its not working dear.

Comment: try it now, you were doing an assignment in the map function instead of returning a React Node